# problem in sharing genesis block

Tags: go-ethereum

I would like to run two nodes in the same machine which has to share the same genesis file. I tried the following.

**Terminal 1 (Node 1)**

```
$ ./geth --datadir "node1/" init genesis.json
```

It shows successful

```
$ ./geth --datadir "node1/" --port 21212 console
```

> eth.accounts

[]

It shows empty, eventhough there are three accounts are there in genesis file. 
Why it shows like that?

If I put like below then it works fine

**Terminal 1 (Node 1)**

```
$ ./geth init genesis.json
```

It shows successful

```
$ ./geth console
```

> eth.accounts

[0Xadbee , 0xabde, 0xabcde]

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you 've created your account previously in the default blockchain located in the default folder `~/.ethereum/` so when you change the folder its normal that your account are inaccessible by geth. try to copy the `keystore` folder from the `~/.ethereum/` to your new folder node1/ and remove other folders then relaunch your init command